# Offset index by 1 in ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I have a selection dropdown populated by an object like this:

`<select class="form-control" ng-model="nonexistantmodel" ng-options="idx as idx+1 + order for (idx, order) in amazon.orders">`

I'm trying to get the array indices to show up starting from 1. (0,1,2,3 become 1,2,3,4)

But of course `idx+1` only ends up joining the string and it ends up like `01, 11, 21, 31`

I've also tried applying the `number` filter but to no avail:

`(idx+1 | number: 0)` or `(idx | number: 0) + 1` or `(idx | number: 0) + (1 | number: 0)`

but they all seem to just join strings with the same result.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try idx++ instead of idx+1 ?

Comment: @victor175 both `++idx` and `idx++` causes a parser error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change `idx+1` with `idx*1+1` or `idx/1+1` or `idx-0+1`.

See a [live example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaqvON).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Angular is treating the index of the array as a string. You'll need to pass it to a function that will parse it to an integer and add 1 to it, returning that result.

I recommend making a simple filter:

```
app.filter('plus1', function() {
  return function(input) {
    var i = parseInt(input, 10);
    return i+1;
  };
});
```

Then your expression will look like this:

```
idx as (idx|plus1) + order for (idx, order) in amazon.orders
```

Or you can put something like this in your controller:

```
$scope.indexBy1 = function(index) {
  var i = parseInt(index, 10);
  return i+1;
};
```

Then your expression in `ng-options` will look like this:

```
idx as indexBy1(idx) + order for (idx, order) in amazon.orders
```

[Here's a JSBin.](http://jsbin.com/rifovizuhe/1/edit?html,js,output)